# Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in line 7

Tags: php

I'm trying to be proxy but getting this error:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in C:\wamp64\www\float\form.php on line 7

my form.php

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

$file = file_get_contents("https://lichess.org/api/user/$_POST[name]");
$json = json_decode($file);

echo $json;
?>
```

my index.html

```
<form action="form" method="post">
<p>Username <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

When i disable `$json = json_decode($file);` i can get full JSON output without errors.

Comment: Why do you `json_decode` the result?

Comment: Requested JSON sends me a lot of values, i want to show only few of them. @tkausl

Comment: `$_POST[name]` <---- doesn't look right, forgot single quotes around `name`?

Comment: Im getting same error..

Comment: use encode `$json = json_encode($json)` after decode

Comment: Then whats the point of encoding @TigerTV.ru

Comment: @3mirhan: json_decode return object, json_encode return string. You've said you need to change output, change object after decode, and than do output.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the error because the object returned by function `json_encode` doesn't have function `__toString` to represent the object as a string:

So, if you don't want to get full output `https://lichess.org/api/user/$_POST[name]`
you should change the object returned by function `json_encode` and then do `json_decode` which return a json string.

Also you can add `__toString` on the fly to the object(it will work only for php>5.2):

```
$json = json_decode($file);
$json->__toString = function () { return "a presentation of the object"; };
echo $json
```

Also you need change the line:

`$file = file_get_contents("https://lichess.org/api/user/$_POST[name]");`

on

`$file = file_get_contents('https://lichess.org/api/user/'+$_POST['name']);`

Answer (score 0):

I got this when encoding XML data, where empty elements were represented as `{}` (object). Solved this by replacing `{}` with `""` before returning:

```
return str_replace(': {}',': ""',json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```